# UISwitch Throwing Fault Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, ios13, uiswitch

All.

I have had a look through, struggling to find an answer. For the life of me I know I can figure it out, however, I am struggling.

The below code executes and pushes changeURL to another view controller. This changeURL variable is set to an 'if' statement where true appends one string to the URL and false appends another.

The API works fine. Everything works as it should.

However, When I load the initial view below the UISwitch is already on. I hit enter and I get the return table view populated with content.

```
import UIKit

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var warningLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var clickToEnterButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var explicitSwitch: UISwitch!

    //    @IBAction func urlSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    //        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTableView", sender: explicitSwitch)
    //    }
    @IBAction func enterButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTableView", sender: clickToEnterButton)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.destination is JokesTableViewController {
            let vc = segue.destination as? JokesTableViewController
            vc?.changeURL = explicitSwitch.isOn
        }
    }
}
```

If I then switch the UISwitch to the 'off' position it throws a fault.

```
'invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.'
```

**I know the switch is working because if I set the switch to false after accessing the view and then clicking enter again it presents me with the second API - code below.**

```
import UIKit

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var warningLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var clickToEnterButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var explicitSwitch: UISwitch!

    //    @IBAction func urlSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    //        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTableView", sender: explicitSwitch)
    //    }
    @IBAction func enterButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTableView", sender: clickToEnterButton)

    }

    func explicitSwitchOff(){
        explicitSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.destination is JokesTableViewController {
            let vc = segue.destination as? JokesTableViewController
            vc?.changeURL = explicitSwitch.isOn
            explicitSwitchOff()
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I think I need to separate the value of the switch (true or false) from the UISwitch action. Then attach it to the UIButton action?

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Kishan. I did come across that solution. I am struggling to understand it without a visual aid though!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have found the answer.

It turns out the UISwitch was still declared to a variable which wasn't there!

Lesson learnt.